# Skype install on 14.04 Tried to trace the problem

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, skype, multiarch

I tried to install Skype on Ubuntu 14.04. I think i traced the problem back and need help.

First i checked if multiarch is enabled.

```
localhost@localhost-W54-55SU1-SUW:~$ dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
```

and

```
localhost@localhost-W54-55SU1-SUW:~$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
```

at least

```
localhost@localhost-W54-55SU1-SUW:~$ cat /var/lib/dpkg/arch 
amd64
i386
```

Now it tried to trace back on the package dependencies to find the mad package.

```
localhost@localhost-W54-55SU1-SUW:~$ sudo apt-get --simulate install skype
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
skype : Depends: skype-bin
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


localhost@localhost-W54-55SU1-SUW:~$ sudo apt-get --simulate install skype-bin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype-bin:i386 : Depends: libqtwebkit4:i386 (>= 2.2~2011week36) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.



localhost@localhost-W54-55SU1-SUW:~$ sudo apt-get --simulate install     libqtwebkit4:i386 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqtwebkit4:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be     installed or
                          libgl1:i386
                 Depends: libqt4-opengl:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.



localhost@localhost-W54-55SU1-SUW:~$ sudo apt-get --simulate install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.3.1) but it is not going to be     installed
                    Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.2) but it is not     going to be installed
                    Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 7.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

localhost@localhost-W54-55SU1-SUW:~$ sudo apt-get --simulate install libdrm2:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx but it is not going to be installed or
                           libgl1
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

On the last package libglapi-mesa:i386 he will get rid of nearly all programs i use...

```
localhost@localhost-W54-55SU1-SUW:~$ sudo apt-get --simulate install libglapi-mesa:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
 asymptote-doc cheese-common gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0
 gnome-video-effects ibus-qt4 libaccounts-glib0 libdmapsharing-3.0-2
  libebackend-1.2-7 libebook-1.2-14 libedata-book-1.2-20 libgc1c2 libgee-0.8-2
 libgexiv2-2 libgpod-common libgpod4 libgsl0ldbl libibus-qt1 libpeas-1.0-0
  libpeas-common libraw9 librest-0.7-0 libsgutils2-2 libsignon-glib1
  libwxbase2.8-0 pgadmin3-data pgagent python-imaging-tk python-netifaces
  python3-mako python3-markupsafe rhythmbox-data shotwell-common texmaker-data
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  asymptote brasero cheese epson-inkjet-printer-escpr
  epson-inkjet-printer-workforce-635-nx625-series freeglut3 gimp gir1.2-rb-3.0
  gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gnome-user-guide gnumeric-doc gstreamer1.0-clutter
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gufw gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse
  kde-runtime kdelibs5-plugins kubuntu-debug-installer leap libcheese-gtk23
  libcheese7 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-gst-2.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0
  libcogl-pango15 libcogl15 libegl1-mesa-drivers libgl1-mesa-glx libglamor0
  libglapi-mesa libgles2-mesa libglu1-mesa libgnome-desktop-3-7 libgtkglext1
  libkactivities-bin libkdewebkit5 libokularcore4 libopencv-calib3d2.4
  libopencv-contrib2.4 libopencv-core2.4 libopencv-features2d2.4
  libopencv-flann2.4 libopencv-highgui2.4 libopencv-imgproc2.4
  libopencv-legacy2.4 libopencv-ml2.4 libopencv-objdetect2.4
  libopencv-video2.4 libplasma3 libqt4-opengl libqtwebkit4 librhythmbox-core8
  libvisual-0.4-plugins libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwxgtk2.8-0
  libyelp0 lsb lsb-desktop lsb-graphics mplayer nautilus nautilus-sendto
  okular pgadmin3 phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer phonon-backend-gstreamer1.0
  plasma-scriptengine-javascript python-qt4 qapt-batch rhythmbox
  rhythmbox-mozilla rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist
  rhythmbox-plugins shotwell software-center steam-launcher texmaker
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk update-manager update-notifier x11-utils xorg
  xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all
  xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-mouse
  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-ati
  xserver-xorg-video-cirrus xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
  xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl xserver-xorg-video-intel
  xserver-xorg-video-mach64 xserver-xorg-video-mga
  xserver-xorg-video-modesetting xserver-xorg-video-neomagic
  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-openchrome
  xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-r128 xserver-xorg-video-radeon
  xserver-xorg-video-s3 xserver-xorg-video-savage
  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion xserver-xorg-video-sis
  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb xserver-xorg-video-tdfx xserver-xorg-video-trident
  xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware xubuntu-desktop yelp
  zenity
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libglapi-mesa:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 123 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Remv asymptote [2.15-2build2]
Remv brasero [3.10.0-0ubuntu1]
Remv cheese [3.10.2-0ubuntu2]
Remv epson-inkjet-printer-escpr [1.4.4-1lsb3.2]
...
```

I looked the packages up in my dpkg and i've all packages as amd64 version. How can i install the i386 versions, which Skype needs without get rid of these 123 amd64 packages?

**Update:** The Canonical Partner repository is added and active.

**Update2:** The result of apt-cache policy libglapi-mesa and apt-cache policy libglapi-mesa:i386.

```
haskeer@sanktuario-tuxedo:~$ apt-cache policy libglapi-mesa
libglapi-mesa:
 Installed: 10.5.0~git20141122.3d9c1a9d-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty
  Candidate: 10.5.0~git20141122.3d9c1a9d-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty
  Version table:
 *** 10.5.0~git20141122.3d9c1a9d-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty 0
    500 http://deb.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.2 0
    500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
 10.1.0-4ubuntu5 0
    500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
haskeer@sanktuario-tuxedo:~$ apt-cache policy libglapi-mesa:i386
libglapi-mesa:i386:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.2
Version table:
 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.2 0
    500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
 10.1.0-4ubuntu5 0
    500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: Haven't read all the stuff you provided, but first the basic question: Is [Canonical Partners](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html#canonical-partner) activated? Next: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install skype skype-bin`?

Comment: @haskeer: Thank you for trying to find the cause of the problem. Can you paste here what `apt-cache policy libglapi-mesa` and `apt-cache policy libglapi-mesa:i386` say? Also, note that commenters aren't notified when you edit your question.

Comment: @saiarcot895 I checked the policy and added the result under Update2.

Comment: @haskeer: What is the `http://deb.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/` repo? Is it something you added? Solution coming shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have version `10.5.0~git20141122.3d9c1a9d-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty` of the `libglapi-mesa` (`amd64`) package installed. Because Skype is distributed as an `i386` program, and by the rules of multiarch, you need to have the same version of the `i386` version of the package installed. However, `http://deb.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/` (the place you got the newer package from) only gives the `amd64` version of the package.

One solution might be to add the [xorg-edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) PPA, which seems to be where that version is from. Both `amd64` and `i386` versions of packages are built in PPAs.

Alternatively, you can downgrade to the distro version of the package (Mesa 10.1.3) by using `ppa-purge`.